# How can I run a Perl script in a different timezone?

Tags: mac-osx, perl, timezone

I need to run a Perl script, but make it think that it is in a different timezone (GMT) than the server is configured to use normally.

I would like to do this without modify the existing script, by means of some environment variables or any configuration settings if possible.

This is for OS X and its vendor Perl (v5.12.4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the TZ environment variable ($ENV{TZ}).
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753346/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-for-perls-localtime for more details

Comment: The code for GMT would be `TZ=GMT perl blah.pl`?

Comment: Pretty much. You can try it out yourself with print(scalar localtime);

Comment: This was the right answer, but the community tends to frown on brief link based answers. The answer here **is** simple to explain, but usually it's not asking much to provide an inline example. I'm giving you the +1 anyway.